# How to make only lower case characters italic in a mixed string

Tags: r, string, expression, italic

This question raised by trying to solve this one [How to write partial string of X labels in italics using ggplot2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72667578/how-to-write-partial-string-of-x-labels-in-italics-using-ggplot2):

**I want to know how we could only italicize characters in a string that are lower case:**

```
string <- "wbfV/wcvB"
[1] "wbfV/wcvB"
```

**Desired output:**

- *wbf*V/*wcv*B

**Background:**
I would like to use it then for labelling in a plot.

**I thought to do it like this way, but obviously it is not working:**

```
library(stringr)

expression(str_detect(string, '[a-z]'~italic(str_detect(string, '[A-Z]'))))
```

which I tried to label

```
plot(1, xlab=expression(str_detect(string, '[a-z]'~italic(str_detect(string, '[A-Z]')))))
```

[image]

Comment: Why is it not working? It seems to be exactly the reuslt your command asks for: only the string in parentheses after `italic` is set in itialics.

Comment: @cdalitz Thank you. The desired output would be: *wbf*V/ *wcv*B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really familiar with using expressions in R directly, I have only ever used `latex2exp`, so I'll be using it here as well. The key to this task is doing the right split with lookarounds. Then you can easily make every other substring italic.

```r
library(latex2exp)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)

"wbfV/wcvBa" |> 
  str_split("(?<=[a-z])(?![-a-z])|(?<![-a-z])(?=[a-z])") |>
  unlist() |> 
  imap_chr(\(x,i) ifelse(i %% 2, x, str_c("\\textit{", x, "}"))) |> 
  str_c(collapse = "") |> 
  TeX() %>%
  plot(1, xlab = .)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

The regex consists of two parts with two lookarounds each:

```
Split between either 
(?<=[a-z])   lowercase letter 
(?![-a-z])   followed by non-lowercase
|            OR 
(?<![-a-z])  non-lowercase
(?=[a-z])    followed by lowercase
```